# SQLAlchemy query model when related model with given properties don’t exist

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have three models (note that this is done in Flask-SQLAlchemy, but if you can only write an answer for vanilla SQLAlchemy, that is fine with me.)  Irrelevant fields are removed for clarity.

```
class KPI(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'kpis'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    identifier = db.Column(db.String(length=50))


class Report(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'reports'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)


class ReportKPI(db.Model):
    report_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('reports.id'), primary_key=True)
    kpi_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('kpis.id'), primary_key=True)

    report = db.relationship('Report', backref=db.backref('values'))
    kpi = db.relationship('KPI')
```

My goal is to find all `Report` objects that don’t measure a specific `KPI` (ie. there is no `ReportKPI` object whose `KPI` relationship has `identifier` set to a specific value).

One of my tries look like

```
Report.query \
      .join(ReportKPI) \
      .join(KPI) \
      .filter(KPI.identifier != 'reflection')
```

but this gives back more `Report` objects that actually exist (I guess I get one for every `ReportKPI` that has a `KPI` with anything but “reflection”.)

Is the thing I want to achieve actually possible with SQLAlchemy?  If so, what is the magic word (pleas doesn’t seem to work…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An EXISTS subquery expression is a good fit for your goal. A shorthand way to write such a query would be:

```
Report.query.\
    filter(db.not_(Report.values.any(
        ReportKPI.kpi.has(identifier='reflection'))))
```

but this produces 2 nested EXISTS expressions, though a join in an EXISTS would do as well:

```
Report.query.\
    filter(db.not_(
        ReportKPI.query.
            filter_by(report_id=Report.id).
            join(KPI).
            filter_by(identifier='reflection').
            exists()))
```

Finally, a LEFT JOIN with an IS NULL is an option as well:

```
Report.query.\
    outerjoin(db.join(ReportKPI, KPI),
              db.and_(ReportKPI.report_id == Report.id,
                      KPI.identifier == 'reflection')).\
    filter(KPI.id.is_(None))
```

Comment: Seems like my problem was that I had no idea how I would do it in SQL. Now that I see the generated SQL it’s crystal clear. Thanks!